Integrate Interactive Book Viewing and Accessibility Features into Your Angular LMS
I'm working on developing a Learning Management System tailored for school students. As part of this project, I need to integrate a third-party library into my Angular project to facilitate viewing books in any format, such as PDF. Additionally, I'm looking for functionalities within this library that would allow users to draw designs, utilize text-to-speech features, highlight text, and create index links. Could anyone suggest any paid or free third-party libraries that could fulfill these requirements?
